# How do I only update some properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

```
Context.Agents.Attach(agent);

var dbEntityEntry = Context.Entry(agent);
dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;

foreach (var name in agent.Properties(true))
{
   dbEntityEntry.Property(name).IsModified = false;
}
```

This code tries to update an entity's properties except the ones which are read only (as returned by the `Properties` field). But I get the error...

> Setting IsModified to false for a modified property is not supported.

So how do I reject the changes on just the readonly fields?

(I tried doing it the other way around and setting `IsModified` to true for non-readonly properties but then the silly computer machine started moaning about how you couldn't do this to reference fields.)

Comment: Can you set the EntityState instead, rather than setting IsModified? Either to `EntityState.Detached`, or `EntityState.Unchanged`?

Comment: Won't that set the state for the whole entity? I only want to un-modify the read only fields.

Comment: How are you setting value on read only property.

Comment: Using reflection. It accesses Properties(false) and iterates over the result reading from the view model and writing to the domain model.